# best fit algorithm

Tags: algorithm, best-fit

I was asked to make an algorithm to do the best fit for some music in the minimum number of folders .

The folders has a fixed size ( like the folders can only hold 100 minutes of music ).

for example :
i have music with these lengths ( 50 - 30 -20 - 20 -80 - 70 -15 - 15) and the folder size is 100 mins .

The result should be 3 folders .

I don't even know how the algorithm works .
any ideas ?!

Comment: Please **research** and come back with a **specific question**.

Comment: Try to find number of possible combination of  `unique` elements whose sum is 100 or any required value.Remember one thing, the elements should not be repeated in next choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like **bin packing problem** which is `NP-hard` Problem.So you have to try every possible combination until the sum of a certain combination exceeds the target number, you can stop calculating that branch and move on to the next branch.

Now you can optimize your result and *count* the minimum number of combinations whose sum is 100 or any target number and that minimum will give you the Number of **folders** needed for storing the data.I hope it helps.